# Windbg local symbols not found

Tags: windbg

I've set Windbg up as the debugger for my development system. And, sure enough If I induce a trap in some of my programs up pops the dialog; I click the debug button; and the source file is displayed with the faulting line highlighted. Mouse over and local vars windows work.

Today, I writing a fairly simple standalone C app, made a mistake and got a trap. But this time hitting debug no source; just the console window.

If I set a breakpoint on main and hit f5, sure enough the source code appears, but the mouse-over variables doesn't work nor the local variables window.

The program is compiled for debug /Zi /Od and the .pdb (& .ilk?) are right there along side the source and executable.

If I invoke the executable under windbg manually, same thing. No source until a run to a break point within it. Then no local var knowledge.

If it can find the appropriate information for one app; why not the other?

Cheers, Buk.

Comment: Are the pdbs located in the same folder as the dlls and/or executable? What does `.sympath` display? If the pdbs are not located in the same location as the dlls or the executing folder then it won't be able to fully resolve your symbols, in which case either add them using `.sympath + 'path_to_symbols'` or via the GUI 'File->Symbol File Path...' (or 'ctrl'+S) and browse to the folder location and add, you should then tick the 'reload' button or issue the command `.reload`

Comment: As I said: " the .pdb (& .ilk?) are right there along side the source and executable.".

Comment: What does `.sympath` show

Comment: ILK is for the linker only. You can ignore or even delete them. Turn on `!sym noisy` to debug symbol file issues.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the !sym noisy command. Very helpful. It appears that my installation is broken some how, because it is forgetting things it should remember. Eg. If I manually set the sympath to .; things seem to work for a few single steps; but if I run to breakpoint; it has suddenly forgotten everything including the sympath. Ditto, it always asks to save workspace no matter how many times I change the setting or check "Don't ask again". I'll try an uninstall/reinstall and maybe a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Windbg doesn't know the location of the PDBs, even if they are in the same folder like the exe. Add the location of the PDBs under `File`->`Symbol File Path` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Comment: That can't be true, because when it is invoked through the WER dialog, it finds the co-located .pdb and source files perfectly well. At least for other programs.

Answer (score 0):

### Debugging symbol issues

If the symbols (PDBs) do not work as expected, use the

```
!sym noisy
```

command to debug the issue. This will display additional information about paths where WinDbg looks for PDB files.

If you change the symbol paths to fix the issue (using `.sympath`, `.sympath+`, `.symfix` or `.symfix+`), be sure to issue a `.reload` afterwards.

### Checking correctness of symbols

If changing the symbol path still does not help, maybe the PDB does not match the executable (should not happen if you just compiled it). Just to be sure, you can use the `symchk` tool which comes with WinDbg.

```
Symchk /if <exe> /s <symbol path> /av /od /pf
/if = input is a file
/s  = symbol file path
/od = all details
/av = verify
/pf = check if private symbols are available
```

or get [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) which is a bit easier to use

```
ChkMatch -c <exe file> <pdb file>
```

### Workspaces

(a question in the comments)

Don't worry about the workspaces and that WinDbg asks to save. You cannot understand the concept without [reading about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx).

Comment: I did read about it. Beyond 'they are of no use to me; so why do I have to learn about about them before I can work out how to ignore them?'; you don't want to know what I really think about them.

Comment: @user3404756: If you want to ignore them, you can start WinDbg with the `-Q` command line argument.